# Como buscar en los caracteres de una celda una lista de valores

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo varias celdas con caracteres aleatorios

- 123456-**foo#1**-rfjas1
- 123456rfja-**foo#1**-s1
- 1-**foo#2**-23456rfjas1
- 123-**foo#3**-456rfjas1
- 123456rf-**foo#3**-jas1

debo buscar los Valores foo#N estos los tengo almacenados en un rango

- foo#1
- foo#2
- foo#3
- foo#4

necesito buscar todos los valores de la lista foo#N dentro de cada celda en la lista de arriba.

realice una funcion para devolver este valor

```
Function BuscarFixed(texto As Range, listado As Range) As String

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To listado.Rows.Count
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(listado.Cells(i, 1).Value, texto)) Then
Else
BuscarFixed = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(listado.Cells(i, 1).Value, texto)
Exit For
End If

Next i



End Function
```

Pero no funciona, ¿Como puedo buscar en una celda cada valor de una lista y devolver el valor encontrado si existiera? agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo encontré! el problema es que `Application.WorksheetFunction.Find()` devuelve un error cuando no encuentra el valor lo cambie por la función `InStr()` que devuelve 0 si no encuentra el valor, con este código se puede buscar un rango dentro de una celda y devolver el valor encontrado.

```
Function BuscarFixed(comentario As Range, matriz As Range) As Variant

Dim resultado As String
Dim i As Long
Dim found As String
For i = 1 To matriz.Rows.Count
resultado = ""
found = InStr(comentario.Value, matriz.Cells(i, 1).Value)
If found < 1 Then
resultado = "no encontrado"
Else
resultado = matriz.Cells(i, 1).Value
Exit For
End If
Next i
BuscarFixed = resultado
End Function
```

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como correcta, y así la pregunta aparecerá cerrada. ¡Gracias!